# drm:No driver support for vblank timestamp query

Tags: drivers, graphics, video, amd-processor

My graphics seems to be lagging a bit.
I entered the command:

```
dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'
```

and I received this message

```
  [2.205753] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
  [2.246056] [drm] VGACON disable radeon kernel modesetting.
  [2.246062] [drm] radeon userspace modesetting enabled.
  [2.246861] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
  [2.246866] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.
  [2.246871] [drm] Initialized radeon 1.34.0 20080528 for 0000:02:00.0 on minor 0
  [2.247838] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
  [2.247840] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.
  [2.247842] [drm] Initialized radeon 1.34.0 20080528 for 0000:01:05.0 on mino
```

My question is, what do the lines:

```
  [2.246866] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.
  [2.247840] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.
```

Mean? I am a newbie, just wanted to know if this is something to worry about, I can't find anything in google.